# The integral $\int_{0}^{6\pi} \sqrt{1+4\sin^{4}t}~dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So is the following function integrable?(not by any approximations). Actually I came up with this integral while doing a physics problem but there it was done using approximations. When I plotted the function it was periodic, and seems to be integrable like ordinary function. But couldn’t figure out it.

$$
\int_{0}^{6\pi} \sqrt{1+4\sin^{4}t}~dt
$$

Comment: Sure doesn't look like it has an analytic form.  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=++++++Integrate+sqrt%281%2B4sin%5E4%28t%29%29+++from+0+to+6pi) gets $28.5228$ numerically.

Comment: Sorry, what you meant by analytic form?

Comment: I mean, that it looks unlikely (to me) that the indefinite integral can be expressed in elementary functions.

Comment: Hmm, thanks by the way.

Comment: $I=6 \pi  \, _3F_2\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{1}{2},1;-4\right)$

Comment: @lulu. Did you notice that $6\pi \times \frac 32=9\pi=28.2743$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  I did...but thought it too far from the numerical value.

Comment: It looks like the final result should be a combination of elliptic integrals.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**$$\int_{0}^{6\pi} \sqrt{1+4\sin^{4}(t)}\,dt=12\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} \sqrt{1+4\sin^{4}(t)}\,dt$$ Use
$$\sqrt{1+4x^{4}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{2 n} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} x^{4 n}$$ to face
$$\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} \sin^{4n}(t) \,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}2\frac{ \Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma (2 n+1)}$$ and continue to arrive to the nice result @Aaron Hendrickson gave in comments

Comment: quick question, you got 12 by counting all the way to 0 to 6pi by the x-axis. How would you do it without using the x-axis? And why did the bounds of limit change as well. I always forget this :(

Comment: @EM4. What about periodicity ?

Comment: Never mind figured it out :).

Comment: Hi Stranger :). One small comment. We should start by considering the expansion $\sqrt{1+a\sin^4t}$ with $0<a<1$. This way the series expansion converges and we can interchange integral and sum.  The resulting series after integration will be $_3F_2(-a)$, which is analytically continued outside $|a|<1$ to get the final result.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson. There is another way. Multiply the result by $z^n$ to get the hypergeometric function and at the end, make $z=1$. By the way, I received quite many comments about the ArXiv paper. Try to submit it somewhere (even if it is not the most pretigious journal). You did a good work. Cheers, Stranger !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I can't argue with that. Touché Monsieur Leibovici! Btw, I did submit it elsewhere. Its in the works.